# parent with autmatic weights giving wierd reults

Tags: rigging

i cant animate that well and i ran across a pre-made animation that i want to apply to my model, it was made for this specific model to the the bones and the vertex groups have the same corresponding names. i just can get the armature with the key framed data to apply to the model.
the model comes with its own skeleton (but its an identical one) and since the model comes in parts it has a skeleton for each part e.g hands, torso, head, ect. but they are all the exact same skeleton

the way that i go about it is i import the meshes and delete the skeletons. 
[image: before i delete skeleton][image]

i then import the fbx of the armature with the animation data and it shows that it indeed has key frames for the animations and if i play it i can see the bones moving but that all. 
[image]

i then set the scale of the armature to 1 as for some reason it imports at a .01 scale so i set that to zero.

i then apply the scale to both the group of meshes and the armature separately by using the old ctrl+a.

i select all and then select the armature and parent with automatic weights and it moves the meshes but it give a weird result.
[image]

i know im doing something wrong but im too no at this to know what, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is a "think outside the box" kind of approach, but consider giving it a try, just to see what happens. No guarantees, of course (and truly, I'm sorry that I wasn't able to address the specifics of your problem more directly). Consider taking the source file, and NOT exporting anything. Start with that file, and instead of trying to extract anything from it, consider using it as is, BUT import your preferred model INTO that file. Once your model is in the source file, with the source file model selected, go into the object data tab in the Properties Panel and change the mesh data block to the one from your newly imported mesh. It MAY replace the source file's mesh with your desired mesh. If it does, then you would essentially have what you want, without doing a lot of work. You could then hide or delete your imported version of the mesh. Please let me know if this works. If not, maybe someone could tell us both why, and how to do what I'm suggesting properly.